# Which syntax to use to render calligraphic symbols like  and ?

Tags: mathjax, calligraphy

I looked at [the list of \mathcal in this reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/15077#15077) but I'm not sure which syntax to use to render  & . I tried also things like `\epsilon`, `\varepsilon` but these do not render the same. The reference says to use the syntax `\mathcal`, but what comes after this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?
[image: mathcal B and E (and bold version too)]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    $\mathcal{EB} \quad \boldsymbol{\mathcal{EB}}$
\end{document}
```

Note that package `amsmath` is not mandatory to use mathcal but is to get `boldsymbol`.

Comment: That's perfect, many thanks.

Comment: You're very welcome.

Comment: btw do you know how to make them appear bold also, I need these symbols for vectors?

Comment: $\bf\mathcal{E}= \left(\mathcal{E}_{x}, \mathcal{E}_{y},0 \right)$ and $\bf\mathcal{B} = (0,0,\mathcal{B}_{z})$ this does not seem to work and I don't know why.

Comment: I edited my answer to add the bold version. Note that you need to use the `amsmath` package to access to the `boldsymbol` command. And you may refrain from using `\bf` in any circumstance, which anyway wouldn't work in math mode.

Comment: I would like to start using this package but don't know how to (what to install etc.?) I was using this syntax instead $\boldsymbol{\mathcal{E}}= \left(\mathcal{E}_{x}, \mathcal{E}_{y},0 \right)$ and $\boldsymbol{\mathcal{B}} = (0,0,\mathcal{B}_{z})$

Answer (score 2):

I have seen your unicode characters. For my humble opinion to me seem be *Cambria Math*:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[math-style=TeX, bold-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[range={\mathscr,\mathbfscr,\mathcal,\mathbfcal}]{Cambria Math}

\begin{document}
\[\varepsilon, \mathscr{B}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

To have bold math of `B`, you can use the command `\mathbfscr`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[math-style=TeX, bold-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[range={\mathscr,\mathbfscr,\mathcal,\mathbfcal}]{Cambria Math}

\begin{document}
\[\varepsilon, \mathbfscr{B}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum** after the comment of the very nice user **@SebGlav**. Here I have use the package `emf` with the option `cmr` (computer modern roman) to have the same calligraphic character. After I have added `scalerel` package to strecth vertically the symbol `\varepsilon`

```
\vstretch{1.5}{\varepsilon}
```

or using `\scaleobj{1.5}{\varepsilon}` to increase the size of the math command `\varepsilon`. I think that the value 1.5 give the same height of the `B` calligraphic character.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[math-style=TeX, bold-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[range={\mathscr,\mathbfscr,\mathcal,\mathbfcal}]{Cambria Math}
\usepackage[cmr]{emf}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}
\[\varepsilon, \mathbfscr{B}\]

\[\emf, \mathbfscr{B}, \vstretch{1.5}{\varepsilon}, \scaleobj{1.5}{\varepsilon}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I agree for the B, definitely. But the E seems really close to mathcal, not to mention the different height. Good input, Sebastiano.

Comment: @SebGlav Thank you very very much for your comment. Now I make an edit using \emf package. For TikZ I have forgotten that many users ask a question to obtain a code and after "take away" :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}     
\usepackage{calligra}

\begin{document}
\centering
\Huge
{\normalfont\calligra E \quad B}
\end{document}
```